# how to extract all values of a XML datasource field to array

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a XML data source like below:

```
<xs:element name="block" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="lot" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="wafer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

Now I want to create a formula which need all block+lot as a string with each record as a single line.
so suppose the data is

```
<xs:element name="block" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" >A1</block>
<xs:element name="lot" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" >B1</lot>
<xs:element name="wafer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" >C1</wafer>
<xs:element name="block" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" >A2</block>
<xs:element name="lot" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" >B2</lot>
<xs:element name="wafer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" >C2</wafer>
```

then the result string is A1B1/nA2B2
How to do it?I tried to use variable and while do loop, but how to let the variable point to next record? Thx.

Comment: Is it really Crystal Reports related? Are you using an XSD file as datasource? If so, may you show the full real XSD file? Where did you try do write the loop?

Comment: NO, I used a XML in ADO.net as datasource and I want to write a formula which which will use a string of all values of two fields combine together.